# Query para mostrar las personas que NO tienen hijos

Tags: mysql

No me funciona la query:

```
SELECT
    NOMBRE
FROM
    PERSONA
WHERE ID  NOT  IN(
            SELECT 
             IDPADRE
           FROM
            PERSONA
             );
```

Para el dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSONA(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(20),
    SEX0 VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    IDPADRE INT ,
    FOREIGN KEY (IDPADRE) REFERENCES PERSONA(ID)
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
    );

INSERT INTO PERSONA VALUES(111,'Abuelo Simpon','m',null);
INSERT INTO PERSONA VALUES(222,'Homero Simpon','m',111);
INSERT INTO PERSONA VALUES(333,'Bart Simpon','m',222);
INSERT INTO PERSONA VALUES(444,'Lis Simpon','f',222);

SELECT * FROM PERSONA ;
/*MOSTRAR EL NOMBRE DE  LAS PERSONAS QUE NO TIENEN HIJOS (bart y lisa)*/
```

No se obtiene ningún error, pero el conjunto de resultados está vacío, cuando debería estar formado por los registros de Bart y Lisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes añadir un `WHERE IDPADRE IS NOT NULL` a la subconsulta en la que identificas a los padres. Ese `NULL` del abuelo te está falseando el resultado porque cualquier cosa operada con `NULL` da `NULL`.

La consulta completa quedaría tal que así:

```
SELECT NOMBRE FROM PERSONA
  WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT IDPADRE FROM PERSONA
      WHERE IDPADRE IS NOT NULL
  );
```

Y el resultado sería:

```
+-------------+
| nombre      |
+-------------+
| Bart Simpon |
| Lis Simpon  |
+-------------+
```

Espero que te haya resultado útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS, tu respuesta me funcionó perfectamente

Comment: Otra opción es un `select NOMBRE from persona where saldoEnBanco > 1000;`. Tener niños es un sumidero de dinero :( Por cierto, si pones los campos en minúscula deberías ceñirte a ponerlos todos, no solo en algunos sitios (has puesto `id` en minúsculas pero `nombre` e `IDPADRE` en mayúsculas!)

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de conseguirlo es:

- Hacer un `LEFT JOIN` a la tabla `PERSONAS` para obtener los hijos
- Y en el `WHERE` indicar que no tenga

La consulta sería:

```sql
SELECT P.NOMBRE
  FROM PERSONA AS P
    LEFT JOIN PERSONA AS H
      ON H.IDPADRE = P.ID
WHERE H.ID IS NULL
```

| NOMBRE |
| --- |
| Bart Simpon |
| Lis Simpon |

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bed461/1)</kbd>